# Unable to create dataset to upload on OpenAI

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataset, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have been trying to create and upload dataset on OpenAI for finetuning of ChatGPT. I have tried both JSON as well as JSONL but none of them have worked. It is continuosly showing the error. How to create our own dataset that will be easily uploaded on OpenAI for fine tuning.

This is the code for uploading json data for finetuning the model.

```
with open("helpnew.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Create a file object containing the data
file_obj = openai.File.create(
    purpose="fine-tune",
    file=json.dumps(data)
)

# Create a dataset
dataset = openai.Dataset.create(
    name="my_dataset",
    description="My dataset description",
    files=[file_obj.id]
)

# Print the dataset ID to confirm it was created successfully
print("Dataset ID:", dataset.id)
```

This is the code for uploading JSONL formatted code.

```
import jsonlines

with jsonlines.open("check7.jsonl") as reader:
    data = [obj for obj in reader]
    
# Create a file object containing the data
file_obj = openai.File.create(
    purpose="fine-tune",
    file=json.dumps(data)
)

# Create a dataset
dataset = openai.Dataset.create(
    name="my_dataset",
    description="My dataset description",
    files=[file_obj.id]
)

# Print the dataset ID to confirm it was created successfully
print("Dataset ID:", dataset.id)
```

This is the JSON data which has to be trained.

```
[{
        "input": "What is a variable in programming?",
        "output": "A variable in programming is a storage location that holds a value. It is represented by a name, which can be used to access or modify the stored value."
    },
    {
        "input": "How do you create a function in Python?",
        "output": "To create a function in Python, use the 'def' keyword followed by the function name, parentheses, and a colon. The function's code block should be indented. For example:\n\ndef my_function():\n    print('Hello, World!')"
    }
]
```

Kindly help me in how to carry out the whole process of uplaoding and finetuning the model.